# Problem in implementing Android rating bar style 

Tags: android, styles

I want to make style for rating bar programmatically. I've read this tutorial 
[Pretty Rating Bar](http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/)

I can do layerList and selector and I can link them programmatically but I can't link the layerList I made with The style attribute programmatically so I can set the style attribute in the rating bar constructor with my own style
 `RatingBar rb=new RatingBar(getBaseContext(), null, defStyle);`.

to make custom rating bar I need to do the following :-

1-make 2 xmls one for the full_empty state and another one for full empty they both include selectors
I made this for example for the fullFilled state:

```
    StateListDrawable state_fullFilled = new StateListDrawable();
    state_fullFilled.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_rated));
    state_fullFilled.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_rated));
    state_fullFilled.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_selected },
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.star_rated));
```

this for fullEmpty:-

```
        StateListDrawable state_fullEmpty = new StateListDrawable();
    state_fullEmpty.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rate));
    state_fullEmpty.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_focused},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rate));
    state_fullEmpty.addState(new int[] { android.R.attr.state_selected},
        getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.rate));
```

2-then I should make layerList of those drawables I've made like this:-

```
Drawable[] d=new LayerDrawable[2];

    d[0]=state_fullEmpty;
    d[1]=state_fullFilled;
    LayerDrawable layer=new LayerDrawable(d);
```

3-I should make this step programmatically But I can't:-

```
<style name="foodRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/food_ratingbar_full</item>
```

Comment: can you post more code, and any exceptions that you get?

Comment: @Justin Shield:I updated the post.

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I'm attempting it myself now, so if you have a solution I'd appreciate if you shared it :)